# Can a user belong to a hidden group in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Is it possible for a user to belong to a group in Linux but that the group name is not listed in the group file in `/etc` directory. If so, what are some examples?

Answer (score 5):

1. It is possible that there are alternative locations for group definitions, as specified in [`nsswitch.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf):

   - [NIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service)
   - [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol)
   - Berkeley DB files, instead of flat files
   - ... and any number of alternative methods that may or may not be available as additional NSS modules in a system.
2. It is possible that a filesystem object belongs to a UID or a GID that has not been defined in `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/groups` or via any alternative name service. As far as the kernel is concerned, that is perfectly acceptable, since it's the userspace that provides the mapping to human-readable names anyway. In that case, userspace tools will typically display the numeric ID instead of a name.

   On the other hand, while entirely possible, having objects with an invalid UID or GID is usually an indication for a problem of some significance - quite often it will be a user that has been removed without proper handling for their files. Such a situation is not acceptable in most cases, because it allows for the possibility of an information leak should the UID/GID in question be reused for a new user/group who would now find themselves owning a number of files from a past user...

We might be able to help more if you mentioned your actual issue...

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have a file that has a GID that isn't listed in groups, this quite often happens if you import files (e.g. tar-balls) from another machine. The group is then shown by `ls` and such as a number, e.g. 4000. For example

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root 4000        0 Dec 24 11:04 foo.foo`

(I did this by `touch foo.foo; chgrp 4000 foo.foo`)

The group file is simply a convenience when it comes to name, and of course to define which users are part of which group.

Likewise, you could in `/etc/passwd` set user `fred` to have group 4000 as a number.

I'm not sure if you can have an empty group name in `/etc/groups`

[And as larsmans points out, NIS may also affect names of users and groups]

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Group memberships might be defined in [NIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service) instead of `/etc/group`. Consult your `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.